# How to get JSON objects from Nodejs server to Android client?

Tags: android, json, node.js, https

I try to send JSON Object from Node.JS server to Android client.

As I look at Stack Overflow, getting JSON object codes are below.

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://172.123.321123:52273/get");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mynum", "1234"));
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.v("UnsupportedEncodingException","UnsupportedEncodingException");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {  
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    InputStream is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    msg = sb.toString();
                    yourregID=msg;

                    JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(msg);

                    String a = jsonResult.getString("myregID");

                    String b = jsonResult.getString("yourregID");


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.v("ClientProtocolException", "ClientProtocolException");

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.v("IOException", "IOException");
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.v("JSONException", "JSONException");

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return msg;
            }
```

and my Node.JS server codes are below:

```
  app.post('/get',function(request,response){
  var p_mynum=request.param('mynum');
  client.query('select ~',function(error,result){
  if(error){console.log('error
  ');}
  else{response.json(result);}});
```

I did postman and result is good. But in my Android device, it occurs:

> JSONException
>
> Error: invalid json
>  & nbsp ; & nbsp;at parase ~

My JSON Object is long string.

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: Error: invalid json
at Object.exports.error (node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:73:69
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:109:7)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
at _stream_readable.js:943:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)